# Custom web-browser in Windows Phone

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, browser, webbrowser-control

What I'm trying to do is to build custom web-browser into my windows phone app that handles users' request differently. I need my code to be notified when a user want's to send a GET, POST or even ajax request to a URL. Then my code handles this request, applies some modification and dispatches the response to the browser.

What I want is far away from what WebBrowser control provides. Do any of you have any idea how can this possibly be implemented?

Regards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you wanting to write a new browser, or are you trying to "intercept" calls from the built-in browser?

If you're creating you're own then you know based on the URL if it's a GET, POST etc. since you'll be handing all socket connections yourself.  It's certainly doable, though it's a hell of a lot of work - just look at how much work other teams have put into other browsers.  Starting with someone else's code base (web kit, opera, etc) would probably be a good short cut to getting the parsing, rendering, etc. working.

If you're simply wanting to create a shim that intercepts calls and massages the return then it can't be done on Windows Phone.  You don't have access to the NDIS layer (a miniport intermediate driver would allow it on other systems).

Comment: Thanks for the information, just another question, I just noticed that for POST redirections .Navigating event is stilled called by I could not find a way to see what are post data. do you know if this is possible?

Comment: Yes, this is another question.  Ask a new one.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7301605/windows-phone-webbrowser-navigating-post-data