# Windows phone WebBrowser.Navigating event form data

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, browser

I have added a handler to WebBrowser.Navigating event and noticed it's being fired also for POST requests. In this case e.Uri is equal to the current Url of the page but there doesn't seem to be any way to get POST request form data.

```
    void browser_Navigating(object sender, NavigatingEventArgs e)
    {
        var url = e.Uri;
        // there is not something e.Form available here...
    }
```

Do you guys have any idea how is this possible?

Answer (score 2):

Based on what I've read recently, access to the Request and Response objects is not possible with WP7 `WebBrowser` for the same reason as the full framework. Basically it was never implemented.

One technique that can theoretically be used to access the form data is the use of a local proxy to intercept requests. I believe this requires the use of a low level socket server on WP7. This is feasible however I'm not sure on whether it's possible to change the phone proxy address programmatically as I've ever attempted it.

Actually one more option. I just came across [this](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/windowsphone7series/thread/2946ad89-fb50-4ccf-898c-b4c5c7a12b54/), apparently you can use [`SaveToString`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.phone.controls.webbrowser.savetostring%28v=VS.92%29.aspx) to save the current document (on navigating). This would allow you to parse the form data just before the form is submitted.

Comment: no it doesn't. WP7 doesn't give you access to .Document. You said option is to "parse the form data" while the question is all about how to access form data!

Comment: Just trying to help, I didn't know about access to document. It makes sense as it's not even possible in the main framework without a COM reference. However I'm pretty sure you can't access request or response data from WP7 `WebBrowser ` for the same reasons I've mentioned. You still may be able to use a proxy technique, I think it's your best bet unless someone knows better. I'll update the answer.

Comment: It looks like `SaveToString` might be the answer.

Comment: interesting, it now makes more sense but still there is a big question: "how to detect if it's a POST request". About proxy I give it a go but I suspect it is feasible to implement in WP7.

Comment: I'd try `SaveToString` first, it seems like a relatively easy approach. Detecting POST is a tricky one, you could do it if you had control of the web page. Without that maybe check the response?