# Intercepting traffic from WebBrowser control and supplying my own data on WP8

Tags: http, webbrowser-control, windows-phone, windows-phone-8

In my Windows Phone 8 application I have a WebBrowser control for which I would like to be able to reroute all http traffic, meaning that I intercept the http GET and supply the data from my app. Not only html but all traffic (image, etc.). I have tried to use the WebRequest.RegisterPrefix to register my own IWebRequestCreate in order to supply my own WebRequests. However, it would seem that the IWebRequestCreate I register is only used for WebClients I instantiate in my own code and not by the WebBrowser control.

I found this thread:

[How to register own protocol using the WebBrowser control?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4689237/how-to-register-own-protocol-using-the-webbrowser-control)

But it would seem that that approach wasn't possible. At least not in Windows Phone 7. I was hoping for better luck with WP8. Or perhaps an entirely different method could work?

Can anybody help me out?

EDIT: As suggested by Josh Mackey below. I might be able to run everything through a proxy. Unfortunately, I'm not sure how to set the proxy to use on a webBrowser control from code on Windows Phone. It would seem that neither WebRequest.DefaultWebProxy nor the wininet.dll is available on WP. Anybody know how this can be accomplished?

Answer (score 0):

As the link you referenced said: "The WebBrowser control will use the Windows Phone Internet Explorer Browser's HTTP stack", so you cannot intercept it. However, maybe a proxy approach may work?

Using sockets, create a simple web server that you could tell the WebBrowser control to access instead?

I got the idea from here: [Windows phone WebBrowser.Navigating event form data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7301605/windows-phone-webbrowser-navigating-event-form-data)

Comment: Yes, that might work if it is possible to set the proxy for the specific webBrowser control. However, i don't see how that would be done. 

I found the link below, which seemingly explains how to set a proxy server, but unfortunately it depends on p/invoking methods in wininet.dll which apparently isn't available on Windows Phone. 

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2563548

I also tried setting WebRequest.DefaultWebProxy (although that would give me less control) but apparently that isn't available on Windows Phone either. 

Anybody knows how this may be accomplished?

Comment: Hi Josh, Considering what is possible with JavaScript, I believe it will be very difficult to account for all scenarios.

Answer (score 0):

What about a simpler solution like using the WebBrowser's Navigating event (which you can cancel).

You'd have to either supply your own HTML when supplying content (which I think would NOT fire this event), but you could do something like this

```
private void webBrowser_Navigating(object sender, NavigatingEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Uri.ToString().StartsWith("myprotocol://", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
    {
         e.Cancel = true; // Cancels the request
         // my custom code here 
         // (where I go get the content and push it into the browser control by
         //     webBrowser.NavigateToString("MyContent");
         // )
    }
}
```

This actually should work in both WP7 and 8.

A couple other things:

1) You will probably have to use your own busy widget to indicate the app is busy as once you cancel the navigation the built in one will not appear

2) You will want to remember to set the "IsScriptEnabled" property on the web browser to true (that is if you need JavaScript enabled.. it defaults to false which IMO is am easy thing to miss)

3) If you need to do post processing on a page you can also handle the Navigated event which lets you override the content when it comes back (or make changes to it)

Comment: For the main html page this could work. However, for frames (with content from other sites), image and other resource, the Navigating event is not fired and thus cannot be canceled. This means that these will be downloaded directly from the server (which is opposed to what I'm trying to achieve). As Josh suggested, I could rewrite all URI's to local references and have my application supply them, but considering what is possible with JavaScript, I believe it will be very difficult to account for all scenarios.

Comment: Yuck! Sorry.. Just looking at your situation and assuming you wanted (essentially) proxy all the calls (and assumed you had a tighter set of pages/URIs you were hitting)... I wasn't really thinking about dealing with frames, etc.